# CSS Property (body's width) = HTML Tag Attribute (table's width)

Tags: html, css

How can I make this code of CSS work?

```
body {
width: $table.width();
}
```

I can't find a easy/simple way of doing this.

The reason is that I have a table and the width of that table is huge, but I don't wanna manually type `xxxxx px`, I want it to automatically change the width of the body to the same as that table. If I don't change the width, the headers of the table get more rows/height to decrease the columns/width so that the headers I'm constantly adding, fit on the body.

I know about other CSS Preprocesors but I would really love to know a way to do this whit "CSS", nothing more, nothing less.

P.S.: I currently use http://codepen.io/pen.

**EDIT:** Said to be impossible, I didn't found a solution myself. No more posts needed (mostly questions) unless with the actual solution as I don't think it will be posted, but, as long as it isn't posted, anyone can post it (I will just not answer but will check).

Comment: Is the table only element inside the body??

Comment: Yes, it has a lot of headers and cells but yes.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

I would personally place the table inside a div.

That way, you can style the div's width to be page width, or any specified amount of pixels/percentage of page width, and then set the width of the table to 100%. This is assuming you have your view port statement set to device width.

HTML:

```
<div class = 'container'>
    <table class = 'tab'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width = 1200px
}

.tab{
    width = 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to automatically change the width of the body to the same as that table

Here is my solution, Pure CSS

```css
body {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

table {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>

  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use javascript to extract out the current width of the table

`var width = document.getElementById('table').style.offsethwidth;`

then calling the function with AJAX and then including the value in the style. However, you will need to use `<table width="$width"</table>`

To be able to extract out the width, you will need to use a GET to call the variable. Thus what you want to do is technically not possible, this is the only way i can see it being done.

Comment: :-)  - but I would turn it around: `table { width: 100%; }`

Comment: @Mr.Guy The table is a child element of the body. It's impossible to do what you ask for.

Comment: Always the "impossible" answer. This is so simple, I don't believe it's  impossible. It's probably just rare for people to run agains this problem or the information about this has different titles/key words. I couldn't find anything, only: use this, use that (I don't know the names but yhe, I only use HTML and CSS for now...).

Comment: updated. @Mr.Guy this is how i think it could be done.